# Fetching documents

Tags: sanity

Using Sanity Studio I've created 2 documents in a simple schema "users" (the structure is not that important), and then updated each of them with some values, and published.

Trying to get the results using the query:

```
*[_type=="users"]
```

instead of getting 2 documents, I've got 4, and it seems each update created a new revision and all revisions of all documents were returned.

Is this how Sanity's edit works each time? If so, how do I just get the 2 documents with all the latest changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably getting both the published and the draft versions of each document. A draft will have the same `_id` as the published document but will be prepended with `drafts.`.

This might be a bit clearer if you modify your query to the following, which will return an array of `_id`s:

```
*[_type=="users"]._id
```

If this is in fact what's happening, you can modify your query to exclude drafts:

```
*[_type=="users" && !(_id in path("drafts.**"))]
```

Here's a bit more [detail about drafts](https://www.sanity.io/docs/drafts).

Comment: Thanks Geoff ! it does work, but is it the proper way to just get the documents ? It looks like a pretty elaborate query to just achieve the same behavior as you would do in any other database / storage solution by just asking for documents of given type

Comment: It's happening because you're authenticated (I assume you ran the query in Vision). If your dataset is public and you query from your front end without using a token, you wouldn't need that extra `_id in path()` part, since an unauthenticated query can't access drafts. To answer your question: Yes, this would be the way to handle it in this case.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much ! I'm actually using an authenticated client from the frontend, that sorts it out :)

Answer (score 0):

@Geoff's answer is correct, however I've found a better way to do this if someone does not care about keeping track of drafts in the first place (my case). You can specify a

```
liveEdit: true
```

flag on the schema type, in which case drafts will not be tracked for this type at all